# Trouble converting TailwindCSS to Pug

Tags: pug, tailwind-css

I am trying to convert a TailwindUI template into Pug. There's one section of the template ("testimonial section") that uses `lg:h-full` and `lg:w-full` to define the height and width of an image. The HTML version of this code works fine, and is included below. My Pug conversion, however, displays the image at an enormous height (1401px) vs. the template. The template renders the image with a height of 464. I have been trying to fix this on and off for weeks, and it's driving me insane.

This is the tailwind CSS in HTML that works as expected:

```
<div class="pb-16 bg-gradient-to-r from-teal-500 to-cyan-600 lg:pb-0 lg:z-10 lg:relative">
    <div class="lg:mx-auto lg:max-w-7xl lg:px-8 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-8">
      <div class="relative lg:-my-8">
        <div aria-hidden="true" class="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 h-1/2 bg-white lg:hidden"></div>
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-md px-4 sm:max-w-3xl sm:px-6 lg:p-0 lg:h-full">
          <div class="aspect-w-10 aspect-h-6 rounded-xl shadow-xl overflow-hidden sm:aspect-w-16 sm:aspect-h-7 lg:aspect-none lg:h-full">
            <img class="object-cover lg:h-full lg:w-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520333789090-1afc82db536a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixqx=LQMNMymkwX&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2102&q=80" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-12 lg:m-0 lg:col-span-2 lg:pl-8">
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-md px-4 sm:max-w-2xl sm:px-6 lg:px-0 lg:py-20 lg:max-w-none">
          <blockquote>
            <div>
              <svg class="h-12 w-12 text-white opacity-25" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 32 32" aria-hidden="true">
                <path d="M9.352 4C4.456 7.456 1 13.12 1 19.36c0 5.088 3.072 8.064 6.624 8.064 3.36 0 5.856-2.688 5.856-5.856 0-3.168-2.208-5.472-5.088-5.472-.576 0-1.344.096-1.536.192.48-3.264 3.552-7.104 6.624-9.024L9.352 4zm16.512 0c-4.8 3.456-8.256 9.12-8.256 15.36 0 5.088 3.072 8.064 6.624 8.064 3.264 0 5.856-2.688 5.856-5.856 0-3.168-2.304-5.472-5.184-5.472-.576 0-1.248.096-1.44.192.48-3.264 3.456-7.104 6.528-9.024L25.864 4z" />
              </svg>
              <p class="mt-6 text-2xl font-medium text-white">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed urna nulla vitae laoreet augue. Amet feugiat est integer dolor auctor adipiscing nunc urna, sit.
              </p>
            </div>
            <footer class="mt-6">
              <p class="text-base font-medium text-white">Judith Black</p>
              <p class="text-base font-medium text-cyan-100">CEO at PureInsights</p>
            </footer>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the Pug conversion that has the screwed up image height:

```
// Testimonial section
.pb-16.bg-gradient-to-r.from-teal-500.to-cyan-600(class='lg:pb-0 lg:z-10 lg:relative')
  div(class='lg:mx-auto lg:max-w-7xl lg:px-8 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-8')
    .relative(class='lg:-my-8')
      .absolute.inset-x-0.top-0.bg-white(aria-hidden='true' class='h-1/2 lg:hidden')
      .mx-auto.max-w-md.px-4(class='sm:max-w-3xl sm:px-6 lg:p-0 lg:h-full')
        .aspect-w-10.aspect-h-6.rounded-xl.shadow-xl.overflow-hidden(class='sm:aspect-w-16 sm:aspect-h-7 lg:aspect-none lg:h-full')
          img.object-cover(class='lg:h-full lg:w-full' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520333789090-1afc82db536a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixqx=LQMNMymkwX&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2102&q=80' alt='')
    .mt-12(class='lg:m-0 lg:col-span-2 lg:pl-8')
      .mx-auto.max-w-md.px-4(class='sm:max-w-2xl sm:px-6 lg:px-0 lg:py-20 lg:max-w-none')
        blockquote
          div
            svg.h-12.w-12.text-white.opacity-25(fill='currentColor' viewbox='0 0 32 32' aria-hidden='true')
              path(d='M9.352 4C4.456 7.456 1 13.12 1 19.36c0 5.088 3.072 8.064 6.624 8.064 3.36 0 5.856-2.688 5.856-5.856 0-3.168-2.208-5.472-5.088-5.472-.576 0-1.344.096-1.536.192.48-3.264 3.552-7.104 6.624-9.024L9.352 4zm16.512 0c-4.8 3.456-8.256 9.12-8.256 15.36 0 5.088 3.072 8.064 6.624 8.064 3.264 0 5.856-2.688 5.856-5.856 0-3.168-2.304-5.472-5.184-5.472-.576 0-1.248.096-1.44.192.48-3.264 3.456-7.104 6.528-9.024L25.864 4z')
            p.mt-6.text-2xl.font-medium.text-white
              | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed urna nulla vitae laoreet augue. Amet feugiat est integer dolor auctor adipiscing nunc urna, sit.
          footer.mt-6
            p.text-base.font-medium.text-white Judith Black
            p.text-base.font-medium.text-cyan-100 CEO at PureInsights
```

If anyone can tell me why the image height is getting enlarged, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`viewBox` is **case sensitive**. Usually it is not converted correctly by automatic converters, although html2pug VSCode extension was fixed some time ago.